# Change element style dynamically with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am trying to get an element and set its font size with puppeteer

```
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const html = `<html></html><body style="width:2000">
                  <span class="text">${text}</span>
                  </body></html>`
    await page.setContent(html)
    await page.waitForSelector('.text');
    let textContent = await page.$('.text')
    textContent.style.fontSize = 150 + 'px'
```

This gives me an error, is it possible to achieve what I am trying to?

Comment: Was exactly is your error? Can you share it?

Answer (score 6):

Use [ElementHandle.evaluate(fn)](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&show=api-elementhandleevaluatepagefunction-args) in this case. So you should do it like this

```js
let textContent = await page.$('.text');
await textContent.evaluate((el) => el.style.fontSize = 150 + 'px');
```

Comment: Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element'.ts(2339)