# Adding styles to ElementHandle objects? (i.e. DOM Manipulation with Puppeteer)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, puppeteer, node-modules

Let's say I want to change the visibility of all elements with the class name `something` in the current page.
I first get all these elements by performing the following:

```
const manyThings = await page.$$('.something');
```

Now this `manyThings` is an array that contains references to all the matching elements in the form of ElementHandle objects.
With this in hand, is there a way to give all the elements in this array a style?

**I want to change all the elements in `manyThings` to set their `visibility=none`, then later, one by one, enable their `visibility` once again in a later function.**

I've tried searching through Stack Overflow posts, but they either ask for a:

`page.evaluate(() => document.query)`

which would mean traversing the page again instead of using the available ElementHandles (which should be faster, right?), or the following solution which doesn't seem to work: [Change element style dynamically with puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64486748/change-element-style-dynamically-with-puppeteer)

This is what I've tried, but `el` is undefined.

```
for (let i = 0; i < manyThings.length; i++) {
    await manyThings[i].evaluate(function (el) {
      el.style.visibility = 'none'; // TODO: Trying to change the visibility of all pages. el is undefined?
    }.call(this));
}
// Now, set one at a time visible.
for (let i = 0; i < manyThings.length; i++) {
    await manyThings[i].evaluate(function (el) {el.style.visibility = ''});
    // Do stuff here...
    await manyThings[i].evaluate(function (el) {el.style.visibility = 'none'});
}
```

Anyone know the solution to this?

Please let me know if there is additional information you need.

Edit:
Here's a screenshot of what the console "undefined" error looks like when I try to print manyThings[i] and el in the first for-loop above:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6yKb.png)

Comment: I believe you run [`evaluate` on a `page` and pass in the element handle](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.evaluate#example-3). so it would be `await page.evaluate((el) => el.style.visibility = 'none', manyThings[i])`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks for the suggestion. But unfortunately, it doesn't work. The 'el' is still undefined

Comment: Well, I'd just do `console.log(manyThings[i])` Maybe you have gaps in your array. Maybe the answers which suggest doing the query in an `evaluate` callback are on to something...

Comment: I've done that too @HereticMonkey. I've checked the value of `console.log(manyThings[i])` in the function, as well as 'console.log(el)'. The former is defined, but the latter is undefined. I'll post a screenshot of what it looks like in the console when I try it:

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass instance of `ElementHandel` inside `evaluate` to make style casting work of init element inside.

Example:

```js
const elements = await page.$$('#testElement');

for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++ {
  await page.evaluate((element) => {
    element['style'].display = 'none';
 }, elements[i]);
}
```

or

```js
await page.evaluate(() => {
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll('#testElement');
  elements.forEach(element => element['style'].display = 'none');
});
```

I tried both on random html structure and both work for me.

If no one of this works for you - so you can have re-rendering after `manyThings` init, so they are become `undefined`. First of all, try my suggestions and then try to add timeouts before init, like

`await page.waitForSelector('.something');`

`const manyThings = await page.$$('.something');;`